# Adding two reminders to ScheduledActionService in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, scheduledactionservice

I am trying to add two reminders to `ScheduledActionService` in Windows Phone application as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScheduledActionService.Find("PomodoroAkshay") != null)
        {                
            ScheduledActionService.Remove("PomodoroAkshay");
            this.Storyboard_Copy1.Begin();
            this.textBlock1.Text = "It's stopped!";
            if (ScheduledActionService.Find("BreakAkshay") != null)
            {
                ScheduledActionService.Remove("BreakAkshay");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (ScheduledActionService.Find("BreakAkshay") != null)
            {
                ScheduledActionService.Remove("BreakAkshay");
            }

            Reminder brk = new Reminder("BreakAkshay");
            brk.Title = "BreakUP";
            brk.Content = "Time up!";
            brk.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20);
            ScheduledActionService.Add(brk);

            Reminder pdro = new Reminder("PomodoroAkshay");
            pdro.Title = "PomodoroUP";
            pdro.Content = "Time for break!";
            pdro.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
            ScheduledActionService.Add(pdro);             

            this.Storyboard1.Begin();
            this.textBlock1.Text = "It's running!";
        }
    }
```

When I press the `button1` on fresh start, `else` gets triggered as expected. However, I get three reminders. Two of them (both `PomodoroAkshay` and `BreakAkshay`) are triggered after five seconds. In addition, `BreakAkshay` is triggered after 20 seconds as expected. However, all I want is to fire one reminder after 5 seconds and second one after 20 seconds. Where am I going wrong?

Additional info: The statement `if` clears the reminders so that `button1` acts as a toggle button.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found what is going on. It seems that reminders are not that accurate when it comes to calculating really small chunks time - like a few seconds. It causes weird behaviour. I changed the `BeginTime`s to a few minutes and everything works as expected. A bug should be filed about the issue.